# How to get the integer of string returned in a Bash command

Tags: bash

I'm running gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay, and I need to use the -ge flag on the returned value, but it is a string, not an integer. Is there a way to do idle-delay.value or something so that I can just get that number returned. Or is there a way to grep the result to get rid of the word uint32?

What I ran:
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay

uint32 500

What I want:
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay

500

Comment: You can use command-line tools like awk or grep to extract the numeric value from the output.

Comment: Bash only barely has an integer type at all. Using a string that contains an integer in arithmetic contexts is normal and expected, and works fine unless there's extra non-numeric characters in that string

Comment: Thus, all you need to do is split your string into two and use the part that _is_ an integer (as far as bash cares) in your numeric expression.

Comment: Regarding "I need to use the -ge flag on the returned value" - it sounds like you're planning to do `if [ $val -ge 10 ]; then`, if so use `if (( val >= 10 )); then` instead, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html.

Comment: I'm not sure how to split my string, and i dont want the 32 part of uint32 either.

Comment: `IFS=' ' read -r type value < <(gsettings ...)` will put only the part after the space into `$value`, after putting the word `uint32` into `$type`. (If you get a syntax error, check that your shell is really bash and not sh).

Comment: @EdMorton the value is a string, so I can not compare it to numbers. I'm trying to extract 500 from the command that I'm running, so that I can start comparing it with operators.

Comment: I know, you're already getting help with that part, I'm telling you what to do after you have it instead of using `-ge`.

Comment: @EdMorton -ge functions well for the problem, i just tested it.

Comment: @SeanHenry, it _works_ in trivial cases, but that doesn't make it ideal. `[ $val -ge 10 ]` is buggy because of the lack of quotes (which means that, say, `1 = 1 -o 5` can turn into `[ 1 = 1 -o 5 -ge 10 ]`, which you shouldn't want to be true but _is_ true nonetheless); whereas `(( val >= 10 ))` doesn't require quotes to make such cases properly be recognized as erroneous, and is also a lot easier for humans to read.

Comment: @SeanHenry, ...not that the extended syntax doesn't have disadvantages -- the main one being _that it's an extension_ and not guaranteed to be available with `/bin/sh`. (`$((...))` is POSIX-standardized and present in every shell that complies with the early-90s POSIX.2 specification, but `((...))` without the leading `$` -- evaluating arithmetic expressions without expanding to the result of those expressions -- is not).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy gotcha, i've seen the warning about using quotes in a few different places so i've been using them, wasn't sure why.